# Why do I get a different result when calculating the probability in a t distribution using a Stat Trek calculator?

Tags: self-study, t-distribution

From [Online Stat Book](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/t_distribution.html):

> [image]

I used the [Stat Trek t-distribution calculator](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/t-distribution.aspx) instead, and got this:

> [image]

Why is the result different from the one provided in the test, and the one calculated using the Online Stat Book [t-distibution calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/t_dist.html)?

Comment: The difference may be that one calculator gives a one-tailed probability and the other a two-tailed. The way the question is worded implies a two-tailed probability.

Comment: @DavidLane - aren't you the author of this chapter? A nice book!

Comment: A great book, really, for a novice like me.

Comment: @DavidLane - I thought that the Stat Trek calculator provided the area from (-2T) to (+2T).

Comment: @CopperKettle It doesn't. It tells you what it calculates -- you can see it's one tailed.

Comment: @CopperKettle It is my book, thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question you have pasted in concerns me a lot.

The premise of the question is wrong.

The answer to the question "*In a t distribution with 10 degrees of freedom, what is the probability of getting a value within 2 standard deviations of the mean?*" is NOT obtained by finding the area under the t-density between -2 and 2.

Unlike the case with a standard normal distribution, the standard deviation of a "standard" t-distribution (i.e. the one in t-tables) is never 1 at any finite degrees of freedom.  With $10$ df this standard deviation is $\sqrt{10/8}\approx 1.118$. So the probability of getting a value within 2 standard deviations of the mean in a t-distribution with 10df is the area under the density between -2.236 and +2.236 (approximately ... and the answer to that is 0.9507)

If the question intends to ask something for which the area between -2 and 2 is the answer, it either has to give those values specifically (like "find the probability that a t-distributed variable lies between -2 and 2"), or it has to refer to the standard deviation of a different variable than the one with the t-distribution (such as the variable on which a t-statistic is calculated).

---

To respond to the issue of why the two values are different, you can see in the output of the Stat-Trek Calculator that it gives $P(T\leq 2)$, not $P(-2\leq T \leq 2)$ -- it's right there in the last line of your screenshot. [It also calls it "cumulative probability", which is a second way of indicating it's calculating the area to the left of its argument]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I never knew about "cumulative probability". Have a lot to read yet, I guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function